# python recursion (exponential)

Tags: python, recursion

Rapid exponentiation, I need to write an algorithm that can calculate n^b faster than n multiplications! The complexity of the algorithm will be O(logn).
I have a code, I was able to pass first 20 test (I can't see the numbers), but I can't improve the algorithm to pass last 5 tests. Any suggestions how can I improve it?

```
def quick_power(x, n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    elif n == 1:
        return x
    elif n == 2:
        return x * x
    elif n % 2 != 0:
        return x * quick_power(x, n - 1)
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        return quick_power(x, n // 2) * quick_power(x, n // 2)


x = int(input())
n = int(input())
print(quick_power(x, n))
```

Comment: You're re-computing a lot of redundant products. Why not use a table and memoize your function?

Comment: This a homework problem ?

Comment: Also, if you are performing floor division, you can perform a bitshift, it's a lot faster. `n >> 1`

Comment: By the way, why not return `x ** n`, it's actually faster in python because it's implemented in C.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I tried  x**n, but was not able to "pass" the test

Comment: The code is fundamentally correct, but as @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ suggested you are doing more computing than necessary (e.g. just square the result of the `quick_power(x, n // 2)` call!), so your problem might be that the code is exceeding time limits (unless this isn't one of those online coding challenges, in which case it could just be your teacher pointing out a *very* obvious improvement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is in the right direction and your code is in principle not wrong. The point is that you need to distinguish two states, even and odd

```
if n is even: x^n = (x^(n/2))^2
if n is odd: x^n = x*x^(n-1)
```

, which you actually did.

Without knowing your last 5 tests, it is hard to figure out why it failed. But you can try the following simplified code.

```
def quick_power(x, n):
  if n == 0:
    return 1
  elif n % 2 == 0:
    return quick_power(x, n / 2)**2
  else:
    return x * quick_power(x, n-1)

print(quick_power(3, 5))
```